# String format compare in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, string-formatting, string-comparison

hello all i have one `NSString`  in this format `+1-123-123-1234` (phone number US base style) , my question is How can we compare that my string is formted in `+1-123-123-1234` format .

on the basic of String compare formatted i have to done another task ..so any one have any idea regarding same please help me .

Comment: You should use NSRegularExpression I suppose

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `NSRegularExpression` to test if your string is of a certain format.

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
    regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^\\+\\d-\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}$"
                         options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                           error:nil];

int num = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:phoneNumberHere
                                 options:0
                                   range:NSMakeRange(0, [phoneNUmberHere length])];
if (num == 1) {
    // match!
}
```

Comment: I think that first `\\d` can be simply `1` if OP is testing US phone numbers only, although the only other single-digit country code is +7 for Russia.

Comment: This is only true for iOS 4.0 and higher.  If you find yourself writing code for something under 4.0, then use `NSRegularExpressionSearch` in one of the searching methods for `NSString`.

Comment: when i pass my phone number i got warning msg : 'NSRegularExpression' may not respond to '-numberOfMatchesInString:'

Comment: i cant compare with this warning .. my app crash .!! :(

Comment: Use this method instead - (NSUInteger)numberOfMatchesInString:(NSString *)string options:(NSMatchingOptions)options range:(NSRange)range. For more information, refer the class reference here http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html